# How to Conditionally Change Data in Google Apps Script for Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The problem I am trying to solve involves a google sheet with two separate sub-sheets called "Devices" and "Form Responses." I am trying to automate a Google Form response to update a sheet. The Form Response sheet gives three relevant columns: user_name, an old asset ID and a new asset ID. In the Devices sheet there are two relevant columns: user_name and asset ID. I want the script to parse through the asset ID column in the Devices sheet looking for matches from the old asset ID list. If there is a match it should replace that field with "" and then find the new asset ID in the Devices list and assign the user_name provided in Form Responses to that row.

Form Response:

| user_name | old asset ID | new asset ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| joe | 1234 | 9876 |

Devices:

| user_name | asset ID |
| --- | --- |
| joe | 1234 |
| null | 9876 |

Devices After Script:

| user_name | asset ID |
| --- | --- |
| null | 1234 |
| joe | 9876 |

The way I am currently trying to do it produces errors if a field is null so I am really looking for a nudge in the right direction. I have programming experience, but apps scripts is not like other languages I have used and I am having a hard time finding documentation on it. I am having trouble implementing the logic I would normally use.

Comment: If you wish documentation on apps script documentation try [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Comment: Show your current script and a clear description of the error.See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/  and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

#### You can probably start with something like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Device');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const hr = 1;//header row
  const hA = sh.getRange(hr, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
  let found = false;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    let r = vs[i];
    if (r[idx['asset ID']] == e.namedValues['old asset ID'][0]) {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, idx['user_name'] + 1).setValue('');
      found == true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
      let r = vs[i];
      if (r[idx['asset ID']] == e.namedValues['new asset ID']) {
        sh.getRange(i + sr, idx['user_name'] + 1).setValue(e.namedValues['user_name'][0]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

Here I used [Range.createTextFinder(string)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext) to search for the **old asset ID** and **new asset ID** in the **Asset ID** column of **Devices**. It will return a [TextFinder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) which has [findNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findnext) method that will return the range of the first matching cell and used that range to determine which cell to edit.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  var username = responses['user_name'][0];
  var oldId = responses['old asset ID'][0];
  var newId = responses['new asset ID'][0];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var deviceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Devices");

  var oldIDFinder = deviceSheet.getRange(2, 2, deviceSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).createTextFinder(oldId).findNext();
  if(oldIDFinder){
    var newIDFinder = deviceSheet.getRange(2, 2, deviceSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).createTextFinder(newId).findNext();
    if(newIDFinder){
      deviceSheet.getRange("A"+oldIDFinder.getRow()).clear();
      deviceSheet.getRange("A"+newIDFinder.getRow()).setValue(username);
    }  
  }
}
```

Note: This will not work if either old asset id or new asset id is not found in the range.

### Examples:

**Old ID not found:**

[image]

[image]

**New ID not found:**

[image]

[image]

**Old and New ID found:**

[image]

[image]